# socket.io error on client side in production environment

Tags: node.js, websocket, socket.io

i am working on my carbooking web app.. im using nodejs with socket.io.. in developement environment it worked fine with realtime communication with socket.io.. but when i tried to deploy it on heroku it was a nightmare because its my very first project at deployment stage.. in deployment after i encountered bunch of errors this one is really stubborn showing in browser console:

> net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR

> ReferenceError: io is not defined in **myScript.js**

**code on server**

```
let express = require('express');
let app = express();
let http = require('http').Server(app);
let io = require("socket.io")(http);

app.use("/", require('../routing'));

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
  socket.on('greet',(params)=>{
     console.log(params)
  })
});
```

**Html**

```
    <script src="https://realtimeapp.herokuapp.com:80/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
    <script src="/web-sockets/myScript.js"></script>
```

**myScript.js**

```
let socket = io.connect('https://realtimeapp.herokuapp.com:80')

socket.emit('greet', "hello!")
```

*i think i messed up inscript tag..*

**thank you in advance**

Comment: Your site was working for me... You just need to make sure all your requests use ``https``.

Comment: @Take-Some-Bytes yes all requests are using https..

Answer (score 0):

Did you use below code in server-side

```
  http.listen(process.env.PORT)
```

If you use it then ok with server-side.

In client-side you no need to give the entire URL of the application.
Just use below code

```
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script src="/web-sockets/myScript.js"></script>
```

In script.js use

```
let socket=io()
```

Comment: everything is fine with server side i did use env variables

Comment: Are you sure that you used `let socket=io()`code below `<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script> <script src="/web-sockets/myScript.js"></script>` code. If possible share the github or any link for your code